# JWT claims verification for AWS ALB returns 403 Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-elb, okta

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#user-claims-encoding verifying the JWT claims for an AWS ALB is a simple matter of calling `https://public-keys.auth.elb.$region.amazonaws.com/$key-id`, but for some reason that always gives a 403 Access Denied -error. The region is set to be the same as the ALB, and the `$key-id` is taken from the JWT header (kid). Calling from within AWS network or from local computer made no difference.

ALB is configured to authenticate using Okta OIDC and then forward to internal EC2/EKS boxes. The JWT payload is correct. What could cause the 403?

Comment: Can you check the key-id & region is correct/valid or not? This error can occur, if key-id is wrong or  key-id & region combination mismatched

Comment: Region (eu-north-1) matches the JWT signer and ALB ARN. Key-id is the kid value from the JWT header. Coworker has same issue. They values seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems AWS does not support JWT verification in the eu-north-1 region. Works fine elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an org authorization server or a custom authorization server in Okta? (More info on Okta authorization servers [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-servers/)) JWT's minted by the org authorization server can't be verified locally. [See this documentation](https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Signature-Validation-Failed-on-Access-Token?language=en_US)

Comment: Thanks! This is probably it then. Using the default Org authorization server.

Comment: Testing with a custom auth server did not fix this issue (still 403 Access Denied). This did fix double login with Okta, as cookies for Custom Okta URL (OrgUrl CNAME) worked for auth server. Remote introspection against Okta API of the access token works (signed by OrgUrl itself).

Likely related, I did not manage to verify the JWT using Okta's `/v1/keys` data, as the 'kid' in 'x-amzn-oidc-data' does not match.